# simple way to copy text from vim to system buffer?

Tags: vim

I am working in windows environment and is using gVim for usual editting. I want a simple way to copy text from vim to system buffer so I can Ctrl+V paste to other windows application.

I tried 'yy' and it didn't work. I hate to select the text by click-and-drag -> Ctrl+C because it make vim enter EDIT mode which I can't do search.

It there simple way to do this? Given that 'yy' only require me to press 2 keys, I want a solution within 2 keys too.

Comment: `"*y` will put the selected text into clipboard buffer. 3 strokes though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `yy` to copy into windows clipboard, add the following line to your `vimrc`

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Answer (score 3):

Vim has a *lot* of different  [registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers) that are used by yank, delete, and put commands. By default, the unnamed register is used. There's another register, *, associated with the system clipboard. So the command you want is `"*yy`. Or you can make the unnamed register automatically use the clipboard by setting the [clipboard option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'clipboard').

For more on registers: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers